# Quais são as diferenças entre os métodos AddTransient, AddScoped e AddSingleton para injeção de serviços de depedencias?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, injeção-de-dependência

Estou estudando a respeito de injeção de dependência em ASP .NET, percebi que é possível adicionar os serviços de três maneiras que são:

- [Transitório](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
- [Com escopo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
- [Singleton](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Exemplo:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IMyDep, MyDep>();
services.AddTransient<IValidator<MyDep>, MyDepValidation>();
services.AddScoped<ITodoRepositorio, TodoRepositorio>();
```

---

Conforme o exemplo acima, gostaria de ter minhas dúvidas esclarecidas.

- Como cada um desses métodos impacta no ciclo de vida da aplicação ou requisição em relação ao serviço injetado?
- Quais são as diferenças entre `AddScoped`, `AddTransient` e `AddSingleton`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Primeiro resumidamente:

- `Singleton`: é criada uma única instância para todas requisições. Em outras palavras, é criada uma instância a primeira vez que é solicitada e todas as vezes seguintes a mesma instância é usada (*design patter singleton*);
- `Scoped`: é criada uma única instância por requição. Ou seja, usando como exemplo de uma aplicação Web, quando se recebe uma nova requisição, por exemplo um click num botão do outro lado do navegador, é criada uma instância, onde o escopo é essa requisição. Então se for necessária a dependência (serviço registrado) multiplas vezes na mesma requisição a mesma instância será usada. Seria como um "Singleton para uma requisição";
- `Transient`: sempre é criada uma nova instância cada vez que for necessário, independentede da requisição, basicamente um `new XXX` cada vez que for necessário usar a dependência.

Um pequeno quadro para ilustrar:

| Tipo | Mesma requisição | Requisições diferentes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Singleton | Mesma instância | Mesma instância |
| Scoped | Mesma instância | Nova instância |
| Transient | Nova instância | Nova instância |

O impacto no ciclo de vida é o que foi comentado acima, ou seja, com exceção do `Singleton`, o `Scoped` e `Transient` são impactados pelo número de requisições.

Aqui vale notar que, num serviço sem estado (*stateless*) ou uma aplicação sem contexto de requisição, como um "Console" por exemplo, `Scoped` pode ter o mesmo comportamento de `Transient`, uma vez que se não for possível validar se está numa mesma requisição, sempre uma nova instância será criada.

Para além do que foi dito, recomendo a leitura desse link, que aborda o tema de boas práticas e diretrizes ao usar injeção de dependência: [dependency-injection-guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines)