# e possivel usar varios AddScoped?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou fazendo uma conexão com MySql usando .net 6 no asp.net mvc. Estou usando Interface e a Model no AddScoped em program.cs, mas é possível eu usar varios AddScoped com interfaces e models diferentes?

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BancoContext>(options => options.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=contatosdb;uid=root;pwd=", ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.30-mysql")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IContatoRepositorio, ContatoRepositorio>();
```

Comment: Veja a orientação em [Diretrizes de injeção de dependência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines).*...Se uma classe tiver muitas dependências injetadas, isso poderá ser um sinal de que a classe tem muitas responsabilidades e violará o SRP (princípio de responsabilidade única). Tente refatorar a classe movendo algumas das responsabilidades para uma nova classe...*.

Comment: Relacionado a [Quais são as diferenças entre os métodos AddTransient, AddScoped e AddSingleton para injeção de serviços de depedencias?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528196/137387) e [O que é e como se usa o SRP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/137387)

Answer (score -2):

Sim é possível. O método `AddScoped()` é um método do container de injeção de dependências do .Net, este método é apenas 1 de 3 métodos disponíveis, nele a sua dependência existe durante o escopo definido pelo container de injeção de dependência, você pode adicionar Implementações (sua Model) para a mesma interface ou adicionar outras interfaces com outras implementações. Vou deixar um link da documentação oficial caso você queira saber mais sobre!

[Injeção de Dependência - Microsoft Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)